# CreateFolder() issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an issue with createFolder().
For example the following code creates "fContact" folder but directly on the root folder and not the "fClients" one. "fClients" exists, the Logger.log gives me its name without an issue. It was working this afternoon ....

```
function testCreateFolder() {
var fClients = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B4zXHVhy3OARRktKVUtGVC1hUUU");
Logger.log(fClients.getName());
var prenom = "Toto";
var nom = "Titi";
var fContact = fClients.createFolder(prenom+' '+nom); 
}
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: This is indeed a new issue, please star it to be informed about its evolution https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4471

Comment: Thé issue is now fixed, your code should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here appears to be that you're using 'DriveApp' to get the folder by ID. The DriveApp method  seems to be mostly for managing the root of your folder, and the [description for the function .createFolder() under 'DriveApp' reads](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFolder(String)) 'Creates a folder in the **root** of the user's Drive with the given name.' Whereas the [description for the function 'createFolder()' under 'DocsList' reads](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list#createFolder(String))'Creates a sub-folder with the given name in the **current** folder'.

I tested your code, and when I change the line 'fClients' to:

```
var fClients = DocsList.getFolderById("FOLDER ID");
```

It works as you're expecting.

To be honest, it's not clear to me why these are so separate, but w/e.

Edit: Turns out this was a bug, and is apparently resolved through [this issue link](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4471).

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same problem. Everything suddenly stopped working for me last night... Just changed everything to DocsList and everything works fine again.

Comment: I guess you can go back to DriveApp as DocsList may deprecated some time

Answer (score -1):

Today it works fine again with DriveApp.
A Google temporary issue I guess.

Comment: Issue has just been fixed see https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4471